# Connection refused while trying to push to Harbor registry

Tags: docker, docker-registry, harbor

I am trying to use Harbor as a Docker registry on Ubuntu 20. I followed the official documentation. As I wanted to connect to Harbor via HTTP, I followed the instructions [there](https://goharbor.io/docs/1.10/install-config/run-installer-script/#connect-http).

I am still getting this kind of error:

```
$ sudo docker push harbor_example:5000/ubuntu
Using default tag: latest
The push refers to repository [harbor_example:5000/ubuntu]
Get http://harbor_example:5000/v2/: dial tcp :5000: connect: connection refused
```

Did I miss something in the setup of Harbor and/or Docker?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it works when you specifically add the port 80 in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{
"insecure-registries" : ["harbor_example:80", "0.0.0.0"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
[root@edge harbor]# cat /etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "insecure-registries" : ["0.0.0.0/0"]
}
[root@edge harbor]# systemctl daemon-reload 
[root@edge harbor]# systemctl restart docker
[root@edge harbor]# docker login -uadmin -pHarbor12345 http://192.168.200.45
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
[root@edge harbor]#
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).